# Vertically aligned images floating to the left, and text on the right which wraps if there's not enough space?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create a page using only html and css that has a vertical column of images floating on the left, and text on the right. However, rather than using the usual behavior of a floating element, I want the text to wrap to the bottom of the images if the horizontal space available for it on the right side is smaller than a certain threshold.

Here are some images to illustrate what I'm after. The blue outline represents the page size:

[image]

The page gets narrower, and more text shifts below the images:

[image]

The page gets very narrow, and all of the text shifts below the image, even though there's still some empty space on the right side of the page:

[image]

What I *don't* want is this, where the text gets squeezed into a very, very narrow column and is barely readable:

[image]

However if I use the `float` css property, this is what happens, and I can't for the life of me figure out to avoid it. Here is my attempt at this:

```css
#wrapper{
  border:1px solid green;
}

#left-div{
  float: left;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

#right-div{
  border:1px solid red;
  min-width: 200px;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-div">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YUEcKS.png" />
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YUEcKS.png" />
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>  
  <div id="right-div">
    <p>Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried using flex boxes, but I can't get them to behave the way I want either. The text always fills up all the available space and prevents wrapping from working the way I want:

```css
#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid green;
}

#left-div{
  float: left;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.right-div{
  border:1px solid red;
  min-width: 200px;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="left-div">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YUEcKS.png" />
        </li>
        <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YUEcKS.png" />
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>  
      <div class="right-div">
        <p>Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="right-div">
        <p>Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class="right-div">
        <p>Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
       </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code attempt to show?

Comment: @Kosh I have edited my post to contain two examples of what I've tried unsuccessfully so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly modified your first code example which is using `float`.
The trick is adding a pseudo-element to the right div. The pseudo element has width of 200px and pushes the content down when there is no enough space:

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#left-div {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#right-div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#right-div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-div">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YUEcKS.png" />
      </li>
      <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/2YUEcKS.png" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="right-div">
    <p>Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
      Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you try using media queries to do that. You can set it up your wrapper in order to change its flex-direction propriety to 'column' on smaller screens;

follow this example:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="images">Images</div>
    <div class="text">Text Content</div>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
}

.images, .text {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .parent {
        flex-direction: column;
    }  
}
```

Comment: This gets me pretty close to what I want, but when `flex-direction` is set to row, the text doesn't use the full width of the page below the images. The column of images takes up the entire height of the page. Any way to fix that?